# Retrieve all commits from Git statistics API

Tags: git, github

I want to retrieve ALL commits from Github using [Git Statistics API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits
```

I tried to use `curl https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits` but it does not show me ALL commits, but a few latest. Is there a way to just retrieve the entire list of commits?

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow "[Traversing with Pagination](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/)" in order to retrieve *all* commits, because the result of such a commit query will be most likely paginated.
That is detailed in "[Improved pagination for the Repository Commits API](https://developer.github.com/changes/2014-05-09-improved-pagination-for-the-repository-commits-api/)" (May 2014)

That would avoid sending back a result too big in one answer over http.